# If condition with CTE in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to Create a view where i need to put condition on year and I am trying below code but I get an error. Can someone please suggest if its possible . And the output which is required I have to use CTE only.
Error is as below : incorrect Syntax near ‘if’

Code is as below :

```
Declare @year varchar(20)
Set @year = ‘2022’;

With CTE as 
( 
    If @year = ‘2022’ 
    Begin 
    (
        Select 
            @year , 
            Prev_date = (select    DATEADD(month, -1,GETDATE()))
    )
End; 
Else 
  Begin 
(
Select @year,
Prev_date=  (select    DATEADD(month, -2,GETDATE()))
)
  End;
)
Select * 
From CTE
```

Comment: Can you edit your answer to explain what your actual goal is?

Comment: Why do you want/need a CTE here? Also, T-SQL doesn't support "smart" (single) quotes (`‘’`), you need to use "normal" single quotes (`'`) for literal strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you want to achieve with your cte, but concerning the condition, you can try to put the following into your view / query / whatever:

```
Declare @year varchar(20)
Set @year = '2022';

SELECT [year] = @year, [prev_date] = DATEADD(month, -1 * CASE WHEN @year = '2022' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

`IF`, `BEGIN` and `END` are related to the procedural code, and cannot be used in this context.

Your code, without further specification, can be replaced with the following:

```
DECLARE @Year varchar(20);
SET @Year = '2022';

WITH CTE AS
( 
    SELECT Year = @year,
        PrevDate = DATEADD(month, -1,GETDATE())
)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE;
```

A note and a piece of advice: it looks (am I wrong?) that you are at the beginning of the learning. Try to keep coding guidelines for SQL Server, please. I have made some quick improvements. An example link to follow: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/09/25/sql-server-guidelines-and-coding-standards/

Comment: Thank you i have edit the code . If condition is required because there are 2 scenarios to follow

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple effective query rather than going for CTE which should be used for complex queries.

```
Declare @year varchar(20) Set @year = '2023';
select @year [Year], prev_date = case when @year='2022' then  (Select  DATEADD(month, -1,GETDATE())) else     DATEADD(month, -2,GETDATE()) end
```

Answer (score -2):

You have not give the error and what database you are using.
I suppose you sql should be syntax error, please try this

```
Declare @year varchar(20)
Set @year = ‘2022’
With CTE as 
( 
    If @year = ‘2022’ 
    Begin 
    {
        Select 
            @year , 
            (select DATEADD(month, -1,GETDATE())) as previous_date
    }
    END;
)
Select * 
From CTE
```

`BEGIN ... END;` must use with `{..}` in the case use have multiple statments in between.
Hope this help.

Comment: This code is not working, @Kanakorn.

Comment: Nor will it, a Common  Table Expression (CTE) is an *Expression*, as it';s name suggests. You can't just dump a logical flow operator in the middle of an unfinished expression/statement.

Comment: @GerardJaryczewski I've updated it.

Comment: And it's still completely invalid, @KanakornHorsiritham . Also in regards to *"You have not give ... what database you are using"* Check again; [[tag:sql-server]] is in the tags. Tags denote what technologies the question is in regards to on [so].